# How to get the variable req with ExpressJS and BinaryJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, binary, websocket

I'm doing an upload/streaming server with nodeJS, ExpressJS and BinaryJS for the websocket. Separately, everything works good but the user has to be authentified to upload a video and that's my problem so I need the variable 'req'.

When I use BinaryJS on my express server, I don't have access to the variable 'req' at it is specified in the doc (https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/blob/master/doc/api.md, https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/blob/master/doc/start.md) I use an endpoint but that doesn't work.

When I split the server the ExpressJS server and the BinaryJS server:
Server:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();

var BinaryServer = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;

app.listen(8080);

var bs = new BinaryServer({port: 9000});

function request(client, meta) {
    console.log("request");
}

function upload(stream, meta) {
    console.log("upload");
    stream.write({ end: true });
}

bs.on('connection', function (client) {
    client.on('stream', function (stream, meta) {
        switch(meta.event) {
                case 'stream':
                        request(client, meta);
                        break;
                 case 'upload':
                        upload(stream, meta);
        }
    });
});

console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Client:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="video" id="video" />
            <p id="progress"></p>
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://cdn.binaryjs.com/0/binary.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" />
    <script>
    var hostname = window.location.hostname;
    var client   = new BinaryClient('ws://' + hostname + ':9000');

    $('#submit').click(function(){

        var file, tx;
        file = $('#video')[0].files[0];
        tx   = 0;

        upload(file, function (err, data) {
            if (data.end) {
                console.log("Upload complete: " + file.name);
            } else if (data.rx) {
                console.log(Math.round(tx += data.rx * 100) + '% complete');
            } else {
                console.log(data.err);
            }
        });

    });

    function upload(file, cb) {

        var stream = client.send(file, {name  : file.name, size  : file.size, type  : file.type, event : 'upload'});

        stream.on('data', function (data) {
            cb(null, data);
        });

        stream.on('error', cb);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works perfectly but i don't have access to the variable 'req', so I did like it is specified in the documentation but I am probably wrong:

Server:

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();

var BinaryServer = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;

app.listen(8080);

var bs = new BinaryServer({port: 9000});

function request(client, meta) {
    console.log("request");
}

function upload(stream, meta) {
    console.log("upload");
    stream.write({ end: true });
}

app.get('/binary-endpoint', function(req, res) {
    console.log("get");
});

app.post('/binary-endpoint', function(req, res) {
    console.log("post");
});


bs.on('connection', function (client) {
    client.on('stream', function (stream, meta) {
        switch(meta.event) {
                case 'stream':
                        request(client, meta);
                        break;
                 case 'upload':
                        upload(stream, meta);
        }
    });
});

console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Just this line changes in the client:

```
var client   = new BinaryClient('ws://' + hostname + ':8080/binary-endpoint');
```

But nothing happen in the server, no log is diplayed and I get this message in the client console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1/upload.html [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
GET http://cdn.binaryjs.com/0/binary.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 102ms]
GET http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 26ms]
GET http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 48ms]
GET http://localhost:8080/binary-endpoint [168ms]
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8080/binary-endpoint. binary.js:1341
GET http://null/ [2252ms]
Error: Client is not yet connected or has closed binary.js:1539
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://null/.
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Any resolution for your problem?

Comment: No sorry still no answer, if you find a way let me know ;)